# PHP / Mysql error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

**Model**:

```
<?php 
class Blogm extends CI_Model{

    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function get()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('post', 1);
        return $query->result();
    }
}
?>
```

**View**:

```
<h2>

<?php 
foreach($query as $a):
echo $a;
endforeach;
?>

</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

**Controller**:

```
<?php
class Blog extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Blogm','',TRUE);
    }
    public function index(){

        $data['title'] = 'Sblog';
        $data['message'] = 'My Sblog';
        $data['menu_item'] = array('home','contact');

        $this->load->view('headerv.php', $data);

        $data['query'] = $this->Blogm->get();

        $this->load->view('bodyv.php', $data);
        //$this->load->view('sidebarv.php');
        //$this->load->view('footerv.php');
    }
}

    ?>
```

**Database**:

```
id    int(11)            No    None    auto_increment                                  
    title    text
MIME: text/plain    latin1_swedish_ci        No    None                                    
    content    text
MIME: text/plain    latin1_swedish_ci        No    None                                    
    time    timestamp        on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP    No    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP    on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP                                  
    posted    int(1)            No    0
```

Database has only one entry…

**This is my error..**

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: 4096
>
> Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
>
> Filename: views/bodyv.php
>
> Line Number: 5

Comment: As U can see error is in `body.php`(view) file not in model or controller, show us this file. U are trying to use object as string

Comment: opps... my bad i dint notice it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you are running `->get()` with a LIMIT of 1, it still returns a result set.

What you are actually doing is, looping through your set and printing the single object, which can't be done unless it has a `toString()` method. This is why CI is complaining `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`.

Change your code to

```
foreach($query as $obj):
   echo $obj->property; //where property is a column
endforeach;
```

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($query as $a):
echo $a;
endforeach;
```

The error message is pretty self-explanatory.

You're trying to iterate through the members of the database query object `$query`, and to `echo` its members as strings. At least one of these is an object and thus the error.

Instead, iterate through the resultset represented by `$query` with the relevant API functions provided by your database abstraction.

(Having looked at other activity on this question, it may be that "CI" allows the use of loops as part of this API. Consult the documentation to find the proper way to iterate.)

Comment: I would add that if it's done for debuging purpose a print_r($a) or var_dump($a) statement would do the job.

Comment: @regilero: Not knowing CI I couldn't comment. It's certainly not a catch-all solution. e.g. mysqli resource objects are just that: resource objects. There is no useful data _directly_ contained therein.

Answer (score 1):

i think all what you need to do is add :

$a->title or the info you want ...